# Ionic Angular Closure for trying to return json data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, closures, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic application, that I'm trying to return data from inside a closure. The console is showing everything properly, but I can't seem to get the data to return properly. I've tried a few different variations with no luck.

```
$scope.callbackMethod = function (query) {
 //var ritems= new Array();

  var ritems;

  Inventory.search(query, $scope.currentUser.token, $scope.currentUser.user_id, function(response) {
 //console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
 if(response.success == true)
 {
    $ionicLoading.hide();
    $scope.requestmodal.hide();            
    console.log(response.items);
    ritems= response.items;    
  }
    else
  {
    $ionicLoading.hide();
    //console.log(response.message);
    return $scope.errorMessage = response.message;
   } 
  });

console.log(ritems);
return ritems;

};
```

and also this:

```
 $scope.callbackMethod = function (query) {
 //var ritems= new Array();

  var ritems =  Inventory.search(query, $scope.currentUser.token, $scope.currentUser.user_id, function(response) {
     //console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
     if(response.success == true)
     {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        $scope.requestmodal.hide();

        console.log(response.items);
        return response.items;

      }
        else
      {
         $ionicLoading.hide();
         //console.log(response.message);
         return $scope.errorMessage = response.message;
       } 
    });

console.log(ritems);
return ritems;

};
```

the json that is returned to the script is:

```
{"success":true,"items":[{"id":"1","0":"1","name":"Product 1","1":"Product 1","ref_id":"","2":""},{"id":"2","0":"2","name":"Product 2","1":"Product 2","ref_id":"","2":""}],"message":""}
```

Any thoughts?  Much appreciated!!

Comment: Please share your Inventory code also

Comment: Are you getting undefined in ritems

Comment: @Mohit I added the json response. Thank you!

Comment: @Mohit in the second example I do get undefined

Comment: what do you get on thatconsole.log(ritems)? (at the end of the first function )

Comment: @AnaF I get undefined for them.

Comment: You are getting undefined for both the cases because it is an asynchrounous  call and the console.log runs before the response actuallly comes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this approach to solve your problem

```
var cbm = function (query) {
  var defer = $q.defer();
  Inventory.search(query, $scope.currentUser.token,$scope.currentUser.user_id, function(response) {
  if(response.success == true)
  {
    $ionicLoading.hide();
    $scope.requestmodal.hide();            
    defer.resolve(response.items) ;   
  }
  else
  {
    $ionicLoading.hide();
    defer.reject(response.message);
  } 
});
 return defer.promise;
};
```

and while calling you can then call your callbackMethod like

```
$scope.callbackMethod = function (query){ 
   return cbm(query).then(function(data){ return data;}); 
}
```

Comment: Testing it now. Am I on the right track?: 
 $scope.cbm= function (query) {
    var ritems;
    var defer = $q.defer();
    Inventory.search(query, $scope.currentUser.token,$scope.currentUser.user_id, function(response) {
    if(response.success == true)
    {
      $ionicLoading.hide();
      $scope.requestmodal.hide();            
      defer.resolve(response.items) ;   
    }
    else
    {
      $ionicLoading.hide();
      defer.reject(response.message);
    } 
  });
   return defer.promise;
  };

 
 $scope.callbackMethod = cbm.then(function(data){
    $scope.data = data
 });

Comment: It should work.but,where is it  this "callbackMethod" called?

Comment: $scope.callbackMethod should be the call for it

Comment: yeah..I'm asking where do you use it in html?

Comment: this is placed in the controller for the angular script, but on the front-end <ion-autocomplete ng-model="requestdata.addeditem" value="" items-method="callbackMethod(query)" item-view-value-key="name" item-value-key="id" placeholder="Select An Item"/>

Comment: Okay use.. $scope.callbackMethod = cbm.then(function(data){ return data; }) as your last line

Comment: am I missing a library? undefined is not a function (evaluating 'cbm.then(function(data){ return data; })')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81322/discussion-between-mohit-and-ryan).